# Magento supports PHP 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later error on php 5.6 using system

Tags: magento2, php-5.6

I am using magento 2.2.3 and php vesion is 5.6.3. After running the project It gives error "Magento supports PHP 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read Magento System Requirements." Magento manual says that php 5.6 is  a supporting version.How can I fix this issue?

Edit:
The problem is that I don't want PHP 7.1 because it is not supported by a plug-in I am using. So I'd rather install 7.0.6 or some other PHP version in the 7.0.x series supported by Magento. But I am unable to install a specific version of PHP. How can I specify the exact version of PHP while installing in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You should update PHP to the newest version because Magento 2.2.3 using some function only available on PHP 7.0.x

Comment: Thank you! Previously I have tried to install php 7 by using the command below  
sudo apt-get install php7.0 which installed php7.0.3, That is not supported by magento2. Could you please explain how can I install specific version of php in ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2.2.3 is only compatible with these PHP versions :

[image]

You can find that in magento devdocs here : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Good luck !!!

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain where I will get the magento 2 version

Comment: Your welcome I did not really understand what do you want.Can you explain more to me plz

Comment: I want a magento version that supports php5.6.x

Comment: So then u should install magento 1.9 but for Magento 2 php version 5.6.3 is not supported.

Comment: You can install Magento 2.1 with php version 5.6.5

Comment: ok, I am new to magento, Could you please please explain how can I install a specific version of php in linux machine, I have tried  sudo apt-get install php7.0 which installed php 7.0.3 which is also not supported by magento 2

Comment: You can refer to this link  to install php 7.1 :https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-php-7-1-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-16-04-vps/.  and then your you can run your Magento 2.2.3 project

Comment: after installing php7.1 you will need to install some extensions . You can use this command :                                                                     
                                                      sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-curl php7.1-intl php7.1-xsl php7.1-mbstring php7.1-openssl php7.1-zip php7.1-soap